# Upload build to iTunesConnect with release note

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store-connect

Currently, to publish a `TestFlight` build on `iTunesConnect`, I need upload it, wait for 'processing' to finish, and add release notes into the `What to Test` section. It is very inefficient because it take minutes to process the build before I can add the release notes. So, my question is: Is there a way I can upload the release notes *with the build*, so the notes can automatically be added into `What to Test` before publishing?

Comment: Is there meanwhile a way of doing this? It is still an issue. Why can't we pass the changelog along with the upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload release notes each time you push an updated build to iTunesConnect if you use [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/).

You cannot do this from Xcode at this time.  However, if you prepare your release notes in `iTunesConnect` *before* you upload your build, and save your settings, they will be saved for you.  This way, you can simultaneously wait for your build to complete the processing stage while you're configuring your app profile with the release notes.  Just be sure to save the settings before you select your completed build to add.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know. I tend to disable the build then add my notes before activating the build again.